# SQL Pivot table - filter timestamp

Tags: sql, pivot-table

I have a logger table with timestamp,tagname and tagvalue fields.
Every time tag value changes, the control system writes record to the table with those 3 parameters.
Timestamp for records is not synchornized.
I want to run a pivot table query to get all data for 3 different tags to show the values of those 3 tags only.
When I run the query below, I get in return a dataset with all timestamp records in the table and lots of null values in the value fields(the SQL returns me all timestamp values).
I use the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
      SELECT [timestamp],
             [_VAL] AS '_VAL',
             [point_id] 
      FROM DATA_LOG) p 
      PIVOT(SUM([_VAL]) FOR point_id in ([GG02.PV_CURNT],
                                         [GG02.PV_JACKT],
                                         [GG02.PV_SPEED],
                                         [GG02.PV_TEMP])
      ) as tagvalue 
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

Here's an example to the values I get in return from the SQL Server:

Results example:

[image]

Please anybody can help me how to limit the timestamp that SQL returns me only for timestamp relevant to those 3 tags and not all timestamp values in the table? (the return values list will include a record when at least one of the tags values will not be null)
If anybody have other ideas and not using PIVOT query to get the data in the format shown above - any idea will be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply want:

```
WHERE [GG02.PV_CURNT] IS NOT NULL OR
      [GG02.PV_JACKT] IS NOT NULL OR
      [GG02.PV_SPEED] IS NOT NULL OR
      [GG02.PV_TEMP] IS NOT NULL
```

in the subquery.

Comment: Now another problem, in the same results datatable, I want to calculate,for example, a 2 hours average for each tag, Can someone give me suggestions how to preform it?

Comment: @Amit . . . That is an entirely different question.  You should ask it as a *new* question with sample data and desired results.